# ¿es necesario crear un token al momento de que el usuario se registra por primera vez en la pagina?

Tags: nodejs, angular, tokens, refreshtoken

Según mi lógica, debería de ser necesario, pero estoy siguiengo un tutorial donde crean el usuario solo cuándo el usuario se loguea, pero por ejemplo, hay páginas donde uno se registra e inmediatamante puedes hacer uso de ella e imagino que en esos casos el token debe ser creado al momento del registro para que el usuario pueda acceder a todos los recuros protegidos o estoy equivocado?

otra duda que tengo es la siguiente: Si se crea un usuario al momento del registro, luego el usuario cierra la sesión, y cuándo se loguea de nuevo el token aún no ha vencido, el no se debería crear un nuevo para que vuelva a tener el tiempo completo de sesión? o simplemente se debería seguir utilizando ese token así queden pocos segundos para que expire ? estoy usando tanto token como refrehToken con Angular y Node.js y cada vez se me presenta un nueva duda. estaba siguiendo un tutorial y el token solo lo crean durante el login, cual el usuario se registra por primera vez no crean ningún token y por eso me surgió esaduda.

Comment: Es una pregunta basada en opiniones lo que ocasionaría su cierre.

Comment: a que te refieres exactamente? hice 2 preguntas puntuales y antes de eso he leído y en base a eso es que me han surgido esas dudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Según mi lógica, debería de ser necesario, pero estoy siguiengo un
>   tutorial donde crean el usuario solo cuándo el usuario se loguea, pero
>   por ejemplo, hay páginas donde uno se registra e inmediatamante puedes
>   hacer uso de ella e imagino que en esos casos el token debe ser creado
>   al momento del registro para que el usuario pueda acceder a todos los
>   recuros protegidos o estoy equivocado?

Si vas a crear un registro sin confirmar que el usuario exista, si, puedes crear un token al momento de hacer el registro y proceder como si el usuario se hubiera logueado. Dependiendo de la sensibilidad de tu aplicación, y si es bastante, yo lo redireccionará al login para que iniciara sesión.  Otra cosa es que confirma que es una persona real enviando un correo para que su cuenta se active.

> otra duda que tengo es la siguiente: Si se crea un usuario al momento
>   del registro, luego el usuario cierra la sesión, y cuándo se loguea de
>   nuevo el token aún no ha vencido, el no se debería crear un nuevo para
>   que vuelva a tener el tiempo completo de sesión? o simplemente se
>   debería seguir utilizando ese token así queden pocos segundos para que
>   expire ? estoy usando tanto token como refrehToken con Angular y
>   Node.js y cada vez se me presenta un nueva duda. estaba siguiendo un
>   tutorial y el token solo lo crean durante el login, cual el usuario se
>   registra por primera vez no crean ningún token y por eso me surgió
>   esa duda

La idea es reemplazar el token antes de que expire. Si por ejemplo, el usuario se logue una hora y 20 minutos antes de que expire el token, (con un middleware puedes validar esto) renuevas el token, asi, podrias dar una ventana de 20 minutos a que renueve su sesión sin necesidad de pedirle que inicie de nuevo.

Comment: Creo que lo mejor es esto: al momento en que el usuario se registre, guardo sus datos en la BD y envío un correo de confirmación, una vez que haga click en el enlace envia en el correo se activa la cuenta (y en este momento creo el token) y  puede comenzar a navegar en la web. creo que sería una buena forma, o me pierdo de algo ? otra duda es, si el usuario por ejemplo, nunca hace click en el enlace del correo, es decir, nunca activa su cuenta, imaginno que ese enlace debería tener como un tiempo de expiración, y si se expira, lo ideal seria borrar toda la info de ese user en la BD, correcto ?

Comment: amigo estoy teniendo una complicación, estoy enviando un enlace al correo registrado, al hacer click en ese enlace lo envío a una ruta donde cambio valores de la base de datos, p. ej. la columna "cuenta activa" la cambio de false a true, ahora bien... como podría hacer para que una vez confirmada la cuenta redirija a la pagina de inicio de ese usuario (tomando en cuenta que estoy trabajando con tokens, es decir, para acceder a la pagina de inicio me solicita un token y ese token yo lo creo cuando el usuaio inicia sesion de manera tradicional (con su user y pass).

Comment: Sería buena practica enviar el token en el enlace del correo? para usarlo inmediatamente luego de haber verificado su cuenta ? me registré en Facebook para probar, y ellos te envían un código al correo, cuándo haces click te redirige a una página, esperas unos pocos segundos y automáticamente te redirige a tu pagina de perfil, algo así quiero implementar yo, pero la lógica que ya había hecho con los tokens me está complicando un poco.

Comment: No es necesario mandar el token al correo. Solo un link que caduque y aleatorio relacionado al usuario. Si, es mas complicado. Debes redirijir deste tu backend, en tu controlador.

Comment: Ok, pero como haría para redirigir al user a la página de inicio de dicho user si ésta me solicita un token para poder acceder a ella? ahí es dónde estoy trancado. Yo podría simplemente mostrar un mensaje diciendo que su cuenta fué verificada y que que se loguee para comenzar a usar la página, pero quería hacer de una manera mas simple y rápida para el user, es decir, que se verifique la cuenta y que inmediatamente se re-dirija a la página como un user logueado para que la use de una vez, así como hace Facebook, por ejemplo.

Comment: Entre más experiencia de usuario tengas, mas costo te va a llevar. No se que tecnología usas en el backend. Te recomiendo otra pregunta con el código que usas para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: hice una nueva pregunta y agregue parte de mi código,este es el link:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358788/cu%c3%a1l-ser%c3%ada-la-forma-correcta-para-implementar-tokens-junto-a-la-verificaci%c3%b3n-de

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de como lo enfoques, pongo por ejemplo Twitter en donde puedes navegar sin loguin y pongo ejemplo Facebook, o te registras, o no tienes acceso al sistema.

Un token es como un DNI, cuando demuestras que eres un usuario válido se te da el token y, por cada petición REST que hagas al servidor se lo has de añadir.
**Desde el servidor se validará si tienes permisos para dicha operación**.

Si seleccionas "Log Out" en tu perfil te ha de borrar el token del navegador.
El token por defecto lo guardarás en `window.localStorage` Si te deslogueas, lo borras y haces la limpieza pertinente.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Entiendo lo que dices sobre twitter y que pueden navegar sin se un user registrado. Pero cuándo te registras en una página, inmediatamente se debe crear el usuario, correcto? lo que sucede es que estoy siguiendo este tutorial: https://medium.com/@ricardo.fanizzi/registro-login-con-node-js-express-y-mysql-backend-7eea7440837a y ahí crean el token es solo cuándo hacen el login, entonces ahí radica una de mis dudas. La otra duda era: para los users ya registrados, cuál es la mejor práctica? se crea un nuevo token cuándo el usuario se loguea (una vez

Comment: cerrada la sesión) ? o como bien dices, cada vez que el user cierra la sesión, el token se borra del localStorage y por ende, no habría token que enviar desde el front al back y entonces se debería crear una nuevo ?

Answer (score 0):

el token que que esta creandose al inicio, es un token de sesion único. con tiempo de vida según las especificaciones del token o si se desloguea. Al loguearse nuevamente se genera un nuevo token. Debes tener en cuenta que por seguridad. Hay tokens de sesion y tokens de operacion. en tu caso el que expones es uno de sesión. No se requiere en el registro sino que es mientras se está logueado que se usa.

Para tu respuesta no se requiere crear un token al registro a menos que hables del identificador de tu usuario. Que son temas diferentes.